# Notepad++ backup corrupt

Tags: notepad++

A while ago I was using Notepad++ 6.4.5 and I got a blue screen of death so the pc crashed. after restart I found that the txt file I was working on was blank in windows Notepad and only had the word "Null" if I open it with Notepad++ 6.4.5. so I tried to use the .bak file that is supposed to backup my file at some point but to no avail since I found that the .bak was like the original yet they have the same size on disk as if they were working fine.
So. is there is anyway I can restore the file(anyone of them)? especially since this file contains a lot of random notes and stuff that I don't think I can just write all over again.
and secondly is the backup useful at all?
since I also had that same problem with another file that I could not restore since the bak file was corrupt as well, however I did not care much since it was not important and I already planned to upgrade to the newest Notepad. but two times now did the bak files failed me, so does it work at all?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that either the BAK or the TXT file may have some data on disk beyond the EOF. If the data is important to you, try using a disk hex editor such as the HxD - Freeware Hex Editor and Disk Editor to examine the disk to see if there is any recoverable data.
It is possible the disk itself is corrupted, so it would be a good idea to use CHKDSK to repair the disk **after** salvaging information.

Comment: Not to sound like those people who deserve to have their things lost, but I kinda deleted the partition and moved the files a while ago.
I mean I still have them on another HD altogether. so. Can what you say work? and if so, how exactly would that word? explaining how would it work or pointing my to an article, or the like, would be great. 
thanks

Comment: File recovery is a task for forensic experts or the very persistent. You can see some resources at http://pcsupport.about.com/od/filerecovery/tp/free-file-recovery-programs.htm, such as Recuva, but getting data back requires effort and patience. Would it be easier to rewrite the notes, or to

Comment: rewriting the notes would be impossible, they are a lot of notes about random things that I've written over the years. So I have to try to get them back. now to getting the files back, how can I go about that?
I tried a couple of the programs in your post, yet to no avail so far. but I will keep trying them all. and if you have additional link/articles/howto...etc on the subject it would be great. sine I'm forensic experts I will have to be very persistent.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

oops... took to long to finish editing. One basic technique is to search for a unique block of text in the raw file system, then trace forwards and/or backwards from block to block. Most file systems are linked lists, with at least one forward reference to the next block at the end of each block. Though the tools mentioned, such as Recuva automate that to some extent, it often requires a lot of labor.
If you are lucky, though, some file systems do not actually delete files, but marks them as ready to be overwritten (e.g. by changing the first character of the filename to a sigma). In that case, recovery could be easier if they have not yet been overwritten.

Comment: Just general feedback - SU encourages comprehensive answers.  In general, if you have several aspects of an answer that are related, it's preferable to put them into one answer (you can edit answers and copy/paste).  It looks like you saved your answer before you were through.  You can click on edit to continue or to move text from this one.  Use separate answers in cases where you want to offer two totally different approaches to a solution and it might be confusing if they are mixed in one answer or it would create an extremely long, complex answer.  BTW, you've posted some good answers.

Comment: The thing is, I am running on a new windows install right now. the whole reason I was using the file was to write the endless list of things that I need to do after a new install. and that's why I did not backup the files to my Google drive since that install was just dead with almost nothing working and I though, what is the chances of the windows just crashing while using a txt file and my bak files getting corrupted as well? guess I need to be more paranoid. so it can't work now, right?